# Why running cron tasks would hit a REST service endpoint?

Tags: 7, drush, cron

I can't run cron jobs from a single module or from core anymore. Somehow Drush hits a REST service endpoint.

I have configured some service endpoints for views, but why would cron jobs hit that? I cannot explain that myself.

The error message I get from Drush is the  following one.

> Services Endpoint "rest" has been setup successfully. Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to answer the question directly because we'd have to speculate about the all the possible states of your Drupal installation where [`rest_server_server()`](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/servers/rest_server/rest_server.module?h=7.x-3.x#n23) is hit in a a cron context.

However, since you know where [the notification message is being produced](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/servers/rest_server/rest_server.module?h=7.x-3.x#n35), and you can trigger it in a Drush command, what you can do is insert something like [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) in the `rest_server_server()` function then re-run the Drush command to get an idea of what module/configuration is causing that to occur and if it's causing cron to die on you.